# Multiple wp_schedule_event cron jobs in plugin cause multi-execution

Tags: php, hooks, wp-cron, cron

over the last week I have been working on some cron jobs for a real-estate website that has hundreds of updates/deletes and new posts added each day.  I am very near the end now and looking to schedule three WordPress events to take care of the process.

The code I have linked below runs and send a email to me with the output (with the second and third events commented out).  The problem comes when I remove the comments from jobs 2 and 3.  The plugin activates fine but when the jobs start running I get a lot of duplicate emails.

NOTE** This is a high traffic website that may get hit many times around the time the event is scheduled.  Some of the reading I was doing mention that the wp-cron has had some known issues dealing with long scripts and can overlap.

That being said I am wondering if my cron jobs are too big for the wp-cron functionality to handle.  Does that force me to DISABLE_WP_CRON in my wp-config.php and go with the cron scheduler provided by my host?  Or is my problem in how I have created my plugin?

Thanks in advance!

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'cron_activation');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,'cron_deactivation');

function cron_activation(){  
  wp_schedule_event(time()+60, 'daily', 'first_hook');
  //wp_schedule_event(time()+420, 'hourly', 'second_hook');
  //wp_schedule_event(time()+840, 'hourly', 'third_hook');
}

function cron_deactivation(){  
  wp_clear_scheduled_hook('first_hook');
  //wp_clear_scheduled_hook('second_hook');
  //wp_clear_scheduled_hook('third_hook');
}


add_action( 'first_hook', 'first_hook_function' );
//add_action( 'second_hook', 'second_hook_function' );
//add_action( 'third_hook', 'third_hook_function' );

function first_hook_function(){ 
  //code to run takes 2 minutes.
  //sends output as email to me for inspection
}

function second_hook_function(){
  //code to run takes 3 minutes.
  //sends output as email to me for inspection
}

function third_hook_function(){
  //code to run takes 4 minutes.
  //sends output as email to me for inspection
}
```

P.S. I hope I followed all the correct format, this is my first post!

Edit: To clarify my questions, is it possible to run these (2 to 4 minuet) functions all from the same plugin using the wp-cron method?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem happens because you don't check if your hook is already scheduled.

```
if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'first_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event(time()+60, 'daily', 'first_hook');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general using the [Alternative Cron](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#alternative-cron) *is* more reliable. I tried to make a demo using your example code as the basis in order to replicate what was being seen:

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Overlapping Cron Test
* Author: futuernorn
*/

register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'cron_activation');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,'cron_deactivation');

function cron_activation(){
  wp_schedule_event(time()+30, 'daily', 'first_hook');
  wp_schedule_event(time()+60, 'hourly', 'second_hook');
  wp_schedule_event(time()+90, 'hourly', 'third_hook');
}

function cron_deactivation(){
  wp_clear_scheduled_hook('first_hook');
  wp_clear_scheduled_hook('second_hook');
  wp_clear_scheduled_hook('third_hook');
}


add_action( 'first_hook', 'first_hook_function' );
add_action( 'second_hook', 'second_hook_function' );
add_action( 'third_hook', 'third_hook_function' );

function first_hook_function(){
  //code to run takes 2 minutes.
  //sends output as email to me for inspection
  sleep(30);
  $crontest_data = get_option( '_crontest_data' );
  $crontest_data[] = 'first_hook_completed: '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  update_option('_crontest_data', $crontest_data);
}

function second_hook_function(){
  //code to run takes 3 minutes.
  //sends output as email to me for inspection\
  sleep(60);
  $crontest_data = get_option( '_crontest_data' );
  $crontest_data[] = 'second_hook_completed: '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  update_option('_crontest_data', $crontest_data);
}

function third_hook_function(){
  //code to run takes 4 minutes.
  //sends output as email to me for inspection
  sleep(90);
  $crontest_data = get_option( '_crontest_data' );
  $crontest_data[] = 'third_hook_completed: '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  update_option('_crontest_data', $crontest_data);
}
```

With the normal wp-cron functionality in place, and a contrived set of concurrent traffic, we see just one entry per cron even however:

```
testsite$ wp plugin activate crontest
Success: Plugin 'crontest' activated.
testsite$ for i in {1..10}; do curl -b -s $WEBSITE_URL 1>/dev/null; done
testsite$ for i in {1..10}; do curl -s $WEBSITE_URL 1>/dev/null; done
testsite$ wp option get _crontest_data
array (
  0 => 'first_hook_completed: 2015-11-09 19:49:25',
  1 => 'second_hook_completed: 2015-11-09 19:50:25',
  2 => 'third_hook_completed: 2015-11-09 19:51:55',
)
```

Since I can not quite replicate what you're seeing, it may help to have a bit more information here.